# d3js example not working with php's json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, d3.js

in my d3js example contain [ symbol after children key & working perfectly

```
{"name": "root",
  "children": [
    {"name": "typeA(1095)",
      "children": [
        {"name": "2010(365)",
          "children": [
            {"name": "january(31)", "value": 31},
```

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1283663/raw/a05a94858375bd0ae023f6950a2b13fac5127637/readme.json

but i convert a multi-dimensional array using php json_encode there is no [ symbol so when i pass it to d3js example it's not working

```
$json = array('name'=>'p_date','children'=>array('name'=>'HedCET','value'=>10));
```

json_encode($json) output

```
{"name":"p_date","children":{"name":"HedCET","value":10}}
```

there is no [ symbol after children key, is there any additional option to enable [ symbol in php json_encode ?

OR is there any difference between d3js json file and php json file ?

Comment: Are you passing `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as an option to `json_encode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP

```
'children' => array('name' => 'HedCET', 'value' => 10)
```

is

```
"children": {"name": "HedCET", "value": 10}
```

in JSON.

You have forgotten to put another `array()`:

```
'children' => array( array('name' => 'HedCET', 'value' => 10) )
```